# Disable PIN request for pairing on Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, raspbian, bluez

I'm running a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Wheezy. I have a BT (Bluetooth) dongle attached to one of the USB ports (I have a model B RPi), I've downloaded and installed the following packages: bluez-utils, blueman, bluetooth and libbluetooth-dev, and all works fine.

**But I have a question**: is it possible to disable the PIN request on my RPi side when I try to connect from a mobile phone?

I know how to configure the PIN for the mobile phone, but I don't want my RPi asking for a PIN to pair the mobile phone.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach, which I found to have worked.

- `ps aux | grep applet` (identify the blueman process) and then kill it. This will kill the GUI application. This has to done on every reboot.
- Open the `/usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent` and 
  change `KeyboardDisplay` or `DisplayYesNo` (based on whatever you have there) to `NoInputNoOutput`. Run `bluez-simple-agent` in background and foreground.
- Although reboot is not essentially needed from my experience it is advisable.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the section on pairing a device with your computer in this article titled: [Bluetooth Headset - ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_Headset#Pairing_the_headset_with_your_computer) for tips on how to do this. I do not have a bluetooth device to confirm this but the steps described there may work for you as well.

#### References

- [Ubuntu 12.04 persistent bluetooth pairing](http://devasive.blogspot.com/2012/11/ubuntu-1204-persistent-bluetooth-pairing.html)
- [Bluetooth Security](https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser)
- [Using Bluetooth in a Debian system](https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser)
- [How to setup Bluetooth](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_setup_Bluetooth)

Comment: Thank you @sim, but where is that file located? I think that it is no longer used, at least in Raspbian... https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=539555

Comment: @neutrino - Sorry about that, it does appear to be obsolete. I'll continue to look.

Comment: Thank you again, @sim. But unfortunately, the device I am using does not allow incoming connections. It is designed to search and connect to any device supporting the SPP profile, with a given service name. And hence the problem: the BlueZ stacks ask the device for a PIN, and the device is not prepared to send it.

Comment: If you are using bluez-simple-agent, add capability=NoInputNoOutput in the file, will work only for 2.1 and above devices, also check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729761/bluetooth-bluez-pairing-without-matching-the-autogenerated-pin-on-ubuntu-12-10?noredirect=1#comment32950757_21729761) as well

Comment: @ashish Thanks! But this command: `/usr/local/bin/simple-agent` fail with the message: `Can't set Simple Pairing mode on hci0: Input/output error (5)`

Comment: @ashish Anyway, I will try to set the capability as you suggested, and see what happens. I will post the results.